# HashSet with a custom struct allocates heavy with Contains function

Tags: c#, .net, mono, unity-game-engine, hashset

I am using the `HashSet` collection type which has already significantly improved the performance of my algorithm. It seems that each time I invoke `myHashSet.Contains(someValue)` the internal implementation is boxing the value type immediately before invoking `Equals`.

Is there a way to avoid these wasteful allocations when using value types?

**Sample Code:**

```
public struct TestStruct {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return a ^ b;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (!(obj is TestStruct))
            return false;
        TestStruct other = (TestStruct)obj;
        return a == other.a && b == other.b;
    }
}

var hashset = new HashSet<TestStruct>();
PopulateSet(hashset);

// About to go crazy on the allocations...
if (hashset.Contains(someValue)) { ... }
// Lots of allocations just happened :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lucky guess it looks like the answer is just to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface like demonstrated below. `HashSet<T>` (or at least the Mono implementation) then takes an allocation-free approach to its `Contains` method by using a different comparer implementation.

```
public struct TestStruct : IEquatable<TestStruct> {
    ...

    public bool Equals(TestStruct other) {
        return a == other.a && b == other.b;
    }
}

// No more pain!
if (hashset.Contains(someValue)) { ... }
```

Comment: This is true in the MS implementation as well.  `HashSet` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` (when a custom comparer is not supplied; which is another option you had available to you), which uses `IEquatable<T>` if possible, and if not, resorts to using the `object` overloads.